# Wrap div after another div in jQuery - jQuery PageSlide with Bootstrap work around

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to wrap the div "nav-collapse collapse" before "nav" but after "pageslide"

Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but I am trying to get the bootstrap submenus to play nicely with the pageslide plugin.

Html I currently have:

```
 <div id="pageslide">
 <ul id="nav" class="nav slidernav">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

What I would to acheive:

```
<div id="pageslide">
   <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul id="nav" class="nav slidernav">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("<div class='nav-collapse collapse'>").insertAfter("#nav").append($("#pageslide"));
```

This is targeted for jQuery Pageslide implemented into bootstrap:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Cjn9/44/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **[wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** to wrap your `nav` div with an immediate wrapper. Similarly you have **[wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)** , **[wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)**. You can select the one that meets your need.

```
$('.nav').wrap('<div class="nav-collapse collapse"></div>');
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AUD6/)

Comment: Thanks PSL!!! It works, but for my specific needs I'm trying to get it to work with jquery pageslide and bootstrap and its no dice. :(

Comment: @user992731 hmm ok. Bootstrap should n't be an issue for this. You have an issue using this with pageslide and bs?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to post a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Cjn9/44/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$("#pageslide").wrapInner("<div class='nav-collapse collapse' />");
```

1. [jQuery.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround solution is to toogle your twitter bootstrap submenu with jQuery.